# How to build Scala applications in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: scala, sbt, sublimetext3

I'd like to be able to build Scala applications in Sublime Text 3 on Mac 10.9.3. I have Scala 2.11.1 and sbt 0.13.5 installed and they all work fine. I installed them by homebrew.

However, I can't seem to find how to create a build system for Scala projects. For example, this one doesn't work:

```
{
    "cmd": ["sbt", "test"],
    "selector": "source.scala",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

I found a couple of different ones as well but they didn't work for me, either. Your thoughts?

**UPDATE**:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sbt'
[cmd: ['sbt', 'test']]
[dir: /Users/alex/Documents/projects/scala/dir1]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

UPDATE2:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/sbt", "test"],
    "selector": "source.scala",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

An app:

```
class MainTest extends App {
  println("Hellowa!")     
}
```

The output:

```
 [0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mSet current project to scala (in build file:/Users/alex/Documents/projects/scala/)[0m
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mCompiling 1 Scala source to /Users/alex/Documents/projects/scala/target/scala-2.10/classes...[0m
[0m[[32msuccess[0m] [0mTotal time: 4 s, completed Jun 16, 2014 4:51:38 PM[0m
[Finished in 7.2s]
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "they don't work"? Do you get any error messages, and if so what are they? Does this command work from Terminal? You need to give more information if you want anyone to help you...

Comment: @MattDMo, I'll post them later on.

Comment: @MattDMo, sbt by itself works fine when run from the Terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Homebrew installs executables in `/usr/local/bin`, but the error text you have now provided shows that that directory isn't in your path.

Two ways you could fix it:

1) Change `"cmd": ["sbt", "test"],` to `"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/sbt", "test"],`

2) Add `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable. Note that you'll need to do this in such a way that GUI apps like Sublime Text notice the change; see e.g. [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) for details

Comment: As I said, I can run "sbt" from the Terminal and it works well.

Comment: `$ which sbt 
/usr/local/bin/sbt`

Comment: Just because your shell knows where sbt is doesn't mean GUI apps like Sublime know. Your assumption that there is a single PATH that is the same everywhere is wrong.

Comment: It compiled well but there was no "Hellowa" printed.

Comment: You need `run` not `test`. The latter does nothing because you didn't define any tests.

Comment: no main class detected, I thought it was possible to run a single scala file without having the sbt specific files.

Comment: Ask a separate question? It is possible, but we'll need a new question if you want to discuss details.

Answer (score 4):

Could [SublimeSBT](https://github.com/jarhart/SublimeSBT) that's *"Scala SBT build tool integration for Sublime Text 2 and Sublime Text 3."* be a solution?

Comment: why would I want to use that complex, third-party solution instead of just creating my own build system which much easier? I don't like libraries, I like simplicity.

Comment: You wouldn't since you said *"I don't like libraries, I like simplicity"* :)

Comment: I guess I would, however.

Comment: A sublime build tool will run a command then exit. Sbt works best when you don't close it. It takes some time to initialize and will benefit from JIT. This is why you are better off with SublimeSbt.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use SublimeREPL that support SBT. SublimeREPL allows you to launch SBT from Sublime. This avoided me to download another package, cause I already used SublimeSBT for python. I wanted a minimal configuration to code in scala, because my IDE was to slow. I first try to use my on build system but end up using SBT. The SBT offers great advantages in comparaison to other way of building your project.

First it compiles only files that need to (those who have been modified, and those who depend on them). 
Second it's very handy for importing library. One line into your build.sbt file allows you to import library from github (usually this line is explicited on the github main page).
And  third you can compile on every save, with the command "~compile", or "~; compile; runMain 'mainclass' "

I find the later pretty useful as it is often long to compile with scala. I often start to add a simple function, save, and while it's compiling I improve my first draw.

The main constraint is you have to put your code in src/main/scala or src/main/java if you have some Java files too, and you have to open the whole root directory with sublime.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you :D I am using SublimeSBT for quite some time, and the only complexity it's invoking `cmd+shift+p` followed by `sbt start continuous testing`. I would advice you to give SBTSublime a try before baking your own build system.

Comment: why not to add a single line into  Scala.sublime-build file instead?

Comment: Sure, but this is kind of a Christmas vs Easter discussion, isn't? My advise is to try the SublimeSBT, as you can have it running in seconds, and remove in the very same amount of time, but if you choose to go your own way, and it works for you - even better.

Answer (score 0):

Windows only!
If you already add the bin folder to the PATH variable:

```
{
    "cmd": ["sbt.bat", "test"],
    "selector": "source.scala",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```